# VLOOKUP to INDEX MATCH Conversion

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vlookup

My understanding is that INDEX MATCH is a more efficient process than using VLOOKUP in Excel 2010. Is this correct? If so, I need some help converting my VLOOKUP formula to an INDEX MATCH formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A5&B5,CHOOSE({1,2},EDM.dbo.current_chemical_prices!A:A&EDM.dbo.current_chemical_prices!B:B,EDM.dbo.current_chemical_prices!E:E),2,0) * F5
```

Thank you!

Comment: Pnuts: I had been wrestling with an INDEX MATCH formula for the past few hours. Once I realized VLOOKUP was an option, I was able to script my formula perfectly. Unfortunately, performance was not what I was expecting. Thus my request for help for what I was struggling with initially. Your assumptions are unwarranted. The good news is I was able to figure it out on my own...For some reason it wasn't running as an array.

Comment: INDEX/MATCH is not necessarily quicker nor more efficient than VLOOKUP. It is much more flexible though and it can be quicker in some scenarios. Once such scenario is when you need to return multiple columns of lookups and each can be represented with  the same MATCH. Then you can have one dedicated MATCH column and all of the INDEX columns can refer to it. This scenario demonstrates both the added flexibility and the efficiency that can be gained by the INDEX/MATCH combo.

Comment: Great insight, Excel Hero! Good to know moving forward! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. For some reason, it was not running as an array. Very odd...but solved at least!

```
=INDEX(EDM.dbo.current_chemical_prices!E:E,MATCH(A5&B5,EDM.dbo.current_chemical_prices!A:A&EDM.dbo.current_chemical_prices!B:B,0))
```